# Xpdf pid missing in Awesome

Tags: lua, awesome-wm, xpdf

I'm trying to do some magic with Awesome, generally I suffer from missing Xpdf pid. When I have any other window I'm testing, the client.pid field is OK, and contains the window's pid. However with Xpdf this field is always set to 0.

Is there any way to get Xpdf's windows pid in Awesome, so I could find this window in the clients list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window manager learns about a client's PID because the client tells it about it.

For example, when I run the following command and click on a random window, I get:

```
$ xprop _NET_WM_PID
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 5242
```

However, it seems like Xpdf does net set the _NET_WM_PID property. There is nothing that a window manager can do about this.

Sorry.

(xprop without any arguments gives you a complete list of all the properties that a window has. It looks like xpdf does not set many properties on its windows.)

Comment: Yea, I've figured that out after asking the question. Thanks for confirmation.